# How to change the size of a static array?

Tags: java, arrays, static, size

I need to change the size of a static array.

I have:

```
static int ca [][] = { {45},
                       {0},
                       {45},
                       {0} };
```

and tried:

```
ca[][] = new int[5][5];
```

Comment: You don't. Arrays are *fixed size*, set when you create them.

Comment: Please avoid horrible formatting. Use proper indentation and express your question properly.

Comment: You tried that, and what happened that you did not expect? Think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the size of an array. If you want the same functionality but the ability to change the size, use an arraylist. For an arraylist of int's:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function similar to this:

```
static int[][] ca ={ {45}, 
                      {0},
                     {45},
                      {0} };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ca = increaseSize(ca, 5, 5);
}

public static int[][] increaseSize(int[][] array, int rowSize, int colSize) {
    if (array.length <= rowSize && array[0].length <= colSize) {
        int temp[][] = new int[rowSize][colSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                temp[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily. If you need to be resizing arrays, then use an ArrayList. Here's an example:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(obj);
Object obj2 = list.get(index);
```

"Object" can be replaced with any class or datatype. Check out the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an ArrayList or a Vector. A vector doesn't double the size of itself when the last element is added, unlike the ArrayList.